# Using pgAdmin to manage a Postgres Database on Cloudfoundy

Tags: postgresql, cloud-foundry, pgadmin

I'd like to use pgAdmin to manage a Postgres Database on Cloudfoundy (to build an index on a given DB column). I'm pointing pgAdmin to api.cloudfoundry.com, but don't know what the rest of the settings should be, such as the port.

Comment: hm it's not "problem with code" question, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use api.cloudfoundry.com and expect it to work. Instead, what you need to do is use a feature of CloudFoundry named "tunneling". What it will do is proxy communication between your pgAdmin tools running locally and the remote database running on Cf over http.

This is described here : http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html

Note that if you're familiar with eclipse/STS, an even easier way to setup this is to use the CloudFoundry plugin, as described here: http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/07/31/cloud-foundry-integration-for-eclipse-now-supports-tunneling-to-services/